Movie where friends go camping and miss their country being invaded
I remember watching a movie back in my university days (2006-2011). I want to watch it again, but cant remember its name or much about its cast.
All i remember is that a group of friends goes for a camping trip in woods, when they wake up they see war planes flying over them and then they hear explosion. They rush back to their town, and then there starts the war and adventure. Can anyone tell me its name?

Was it American? Was it from those years or older? When did the plot itself take place (which war was it)? And what was the adventure? (Do you remember anything that happened after that scene?)

i got the answer.. see below posts..

@WillingtodieYoung you should mark the answer as correct if it is correct.
